# What is this dark oily liquid leaking from the drain pipe under my kitchen sink?

Tags: leak, pipe, drain, sink, kitchen-sink

I haven't been under my kitchen sink in a while but recently went down there and found some dark oily liquid puddling directly under the drain pipe.

It was still wet and had the consistency of WD-40.

I turned the faucet on and there is no water leaking. And I have a SmartThings water leak sensor down there and that never tripped, so there was definitely no water leaks.

There wasn't that much of it, and I couldn't see where exactly it came from.

Should I be concerned, and should I do anything here? Wrap some duct tape around the pipe and call it a day?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you notice you have a cracked flange ring? (I think that's the term - the nut holding the pipe to the sink)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first guess?

Food grease/water mix where the water has evaporated..

When hot water runs thru the sink the metal will expand and the cracked fitting will allow leakage.

To test:  Put pan under fitting.  Run hot water for 5 minutes.  Watch for drips.

Comment: Thank you! This appears to be correct. I got a plumber in and he said it could also have been food grease mixed with the sealant putty that keeps the drain in place. He replaced the drain and two pipes below it. Glad I didn't just use duct tape!